# High CPU in windows explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cpu-usage

I'm getting a high CPU usage with Windows 10 file explorer even without file explorer open.
I've run malwarebytes, checked its not built in zip functionality, nor Intel Optane pinning.
Procexp doesn't tell me anything useful. I don't understand why the sub-process CPUs don't total up to the explorer CPU usage.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGUXO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It *could be* malware but I doubt it.  It sounds like a 3rd party shell extension to me.  What makes you think that it isn't avast?  I can tell by your awesome choice of task managers that you are familiar with sysinternals.  Autoruns is a good way to poke around.  I would uninstall avast at least until I figured out what was slowing my system down so much.

Comment: Oh.. !  I should have said that you can use the process explorer to figure out your shell extensions too.  Set the lower pane view to DLLs and highlight explorer.exe and see what DLLs it has loaded.   If you sort those by path, it is usually easy to see the 3rd party ones.

Comment: Explorer is a program that loads libraries from other companies in to Explorer's process space. So to fix without rebooting. *Shift+Control* and click a blank spot on the taskbar - *Exit Explorer*. Press *Ctrl+Shift+Escape* to start Task Manager then *File* menu - *Run New Task* and type Explorer. Autoruns configures what is allowed to load in Explorer. Untick anything you don't want on the Explorer tab. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns PS Run it as administrator.

Comment: What a great set of answers. I have looked at the dlls on procexp and installed Autoruns (brilliant program) and there are all sort of things there - dropbox, avast, onedrive - so I will delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me turn out to be an extension of the taskbar problem. It was [XMeters](https://entropy6.com/xmeters/) and when I uncheck that problem went away.

The process on Win 10:

```
Right-click on taskbar -> Toolbars -> uncheck all
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an infection to me. Malwarebytes of course isn't foolproof. Try another AV/EDR but consider that you may need to backup data and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).